# GET value using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

here is my link

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" class="btn btn-info" href="close_case_edit.php?pw_case_close_id= <?php $row['pw_case_close_id']; ?>">
```

On next page I fetch value using php

```
$pw_case_close_id = $_GET['pw_case_close_id'];
```

but i want fetch this value using ajax as i want update this page using
API

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can i fetch this data using ajax

Comment: *how can i fetch this data using ajax* <- You might wanna google this first and ask questions if you are having some difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) along with [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

A sample working example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var value = $('a.btn-info').attr('href').split('=')[1];
 console.log(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" class="btn btn-info" href="close_case_edit.php?pw_case_close_id=2">
```